# Create menu dynamically but using same view controller [PagingMenuController]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, pagingmenucontroller

I am trying to create ButtonBar based paging menu but it will be dynamic because the data (title for no. of menu) created will come from the server. Unfortunately, there is no such example created for this situation. I know it's really stupid to request such example because I have no idea for this case. I just want to use this library as new because it seems more smooth then other libraries that I used. So, I really need help with an example project is appreciated. And I want to use the same view controller for each different tab like UITableViewController for showing data for each tab.

Any Help with that??? An example will be appreciated...Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to make a synchronous call to the server to fetch the data that i need to populate the menu. It is possible that there is an asynchronous solution but i can't quite figure it out, since my app depends on completely on the menu items.

```
   fileprivate func parseMenuItems() {
    self.menuItems = [MenuObject]()
    let url = URL(string: MENU_URL)
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
        let json = JSON(data: data)
        for (_, subJson) in json["items"] {
            guard let name = subJson["name"].string else {return}
            guard let url = subJson["url"].string else {return}
            let menuItem = MenuObject(name: name, url: url)
            self.menuItems.append(menuItem)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

For parsing I am using SwiftyJson, but that is irrelevant here.

This function (parseMenuItems()) is called before super.viewDidLoad().

Next step is to populate view controllers with menuItems data:

```
override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {
    var children = [UIViewController]()

    for menuItem in menuItems! {
         let child = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TestViewController") as! TestViewController
            child.name = menuItem.name
            child.url = menuItem.url

            children.append(child)
        }
    }
    return children

}
```

Hope it helps :)